# RecycleView conflict with Constraint Layout.(Item view inside recycleview doesn't match_parent)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have simple implement recycle-view. It displays some items.
Each item has a layout like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="#f00"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp">
<TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I found the problem is:

1. If we put the RecycleView doesn't inside constraint layout -> the item view will match_parent (make width to fill parent) -> OK
2. If we put the RecycleView inside constraint layout -> the item view seem force to wrap_content.
   [image: item view doesn't match parent]

So my question is how to fix this problem?
(how do I make recycle-view work well inside constraint layout ?).

**Update**
The view of constraint layout
https://gist.github.com/quangson91/6fae50f5540f8624e71c9eb2f397dfe3

Comment: Show layout xml of `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Yes, I added. Please take a look.

Comment: Change `FrameLayout`'s width & height to `0dp` instead of `match_parent`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just create gist file for all content of layout.

Comment: Please take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the inflater

```
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view,null);
```

with

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
```

Comment: Currently, I am using this one: `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);`

Comment: can you please add your layout file

Comment: Yes, I added. Please take a look!

Comment: Maybe the recycleview size doesn't stable. (Because RecycleView are depend TOP/BOTTOM to some view.)

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your adapter

```
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.ssa, null);
  // below line to change match parent
 RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return yourholder;
```

**updated**

change reclerview

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: in activity layout your RecyclerView and ConstraintLayout width is match parent  ?

Comment: Yes, I set background of both RecyclerView & ConstraintLayout & see it match parent. (The only item view doesn't match parent)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The problem is if I put the layout_height of recycle-view to a special value like 100dp (not 0dp) => the item view inside recycle-view can't match_parent.